# Can't run application on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

When I'm trying to run my application on iOS 8 device or simulator it crashes with messages in console:

```
cwd:/dir=/Users/alexedunov/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0F6F815-1209-48D8-8485-    5B5EB35686B9/data/Containers/Data/Application/65B6100A-22C8-43B3-A6E2-506571B92E66/Documents
cwd:/Users/alexedunov/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0F6F815-1209-48D8-8485-    5B5EB35686B9/data/Containers/Data/Application/65B6100A-22C8-43B3-A6E2-506571B92E66/Documents
2014-09-18 22:57:39.581 BankApp[3943:45325] Wrong directory.
Run application from /var/mobile/Applications/<App id>/<App name>.app
```

I didn't find any solution to fix it.

My OS X version is Mac OS Yosemite beta 10.10.
XCode 6.0 (6A313)

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your Xcode or Simulator installs...

Comment: Try resetting the simulator from the simulator app menu.  If that doesn't work, nuke xcode from orbit and re-install.

Comment: But everything is ok when I'm running it in iOS 7 simulator. Project cleaning and simulator reseting doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. It resolves by removing CryptoPro (http://www.cryptopro.ru/) from project. Probably, in CryptoPro performs find some files in application`s Documents folder using incorrect path ([[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] recommended). I will try to update CryptoPro to latest version, and I hope that helps.

Is your project contains CryproPro?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I'm afraid that latest build of CryptoPRO framework is 3.6.7777 and there is no newer version (https://www.cryptopro.ru/products/csp/downloads).
I'm going to report the problem to support service. Can I use information from your comments in order to accelerate the search and error correction?

Answer (score 0):

I catched the same error when running "Np Cades Browser". I figure out that it's because of iOS version. On iOS 10 error persists.
You need iOS 7 to make this work. Don't know about above versions. I assume paths different on different OS.